# How to install web3 working version in my Decentralized application

Tags: node.js, git, npm, web3js

trying to install web3 and received this error

```
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because
         the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/
         due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t 
         https://github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\elish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-26T15_46_43_457Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have git installed.

You need to install git first.

Download and install from here and then re-run your command
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: yes i installed git and reran the code and i receive the same error